# Yocto minimal image with package management

Tags: linux, build, yocto

I am trying to build the smallest possible linux image using the Yocto project. I would also like to have package management on the target to be able to add to and update parts of the running system.

I can enable the package management by adding this to my conf/local.conf:

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "package-management"
```

Using rpm, that pulls in the smartpm package manager which is based on python which in turn makes the image to large. So I tried to use ipk packages but that still depends on python.

Does anyone have a good idea how to include package management in Yocto with the least possible overhead?

Comment: Did you try `PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_deb"`?     There is also a package class `package_tar` but I do not know if there is an installer like under *BSD that supports such a tar install/deinstall.

Comment: @volker, Thanks, I have tried deb. package_ipk is my main lead now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is the best I can do.

```
PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_ipk"
```

Then edit the recipe for opkg-utils to not depend on python. Will of course break the python utils, though.

Answer (score 7):

I can suggest you few things, which may help you to optimize size of rootfs:

- Optimize as much as possible linux kernel binary and removed unnecessary packages (filesystem,device driver,networking etc).

  ```
  $ bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel //configure as per your requirement
  $ bitbake -c savedefconfig virtual/kernel //savedefconfig
  $ bitbake -f virtual/kernel
  ```
- Configure Busybox and removed unused things:

  ```
  $ bitbake -c menuconfig busybox
  ```
- Remove those Distro features if not in use (and check more also): graphics [x11], sound [alsa], touchscreen [touchscreen], Multimedia. Change apply in `conf/local.conf` file. Example: `DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11 alsa touchscreen bluetooth opengl wayland "`
- Choose proper system init manager: systemd or sysvinit
- Removed Unused Packages from the image. Example `PACKAGE_EXCLUDE = "perl5 sqlite3 udev-hwdb bluez3 bluez4"`
- For small embedded device preferred `PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_ipk"` and it is well optimized for small systems.